# Custom AngularJS directive not showing in Ionic nav bar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have ion-nav-bar and there are two ion-nav-buttons and one custom Angular directive inside (header-logo-dropdown). When I am doing routing or changing browser window size, the custom directive is not showing sometimes, so I have two questions about this:

1) What is the proper method to include custom HTML and directive in ion-nav-bar?

2) What is wrong with the code I've written?

```
<ion-pane ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">

    <ion-nav-bar show-when="(max-width:767px)" class="bar  bar-header  bar-light header-nav-container">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left" id="button--menu">
            <button menu-toggle="left" class="button  button-icon  icon  ion-navicon-round" show-when="(max-width:767px)"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>

        <div class="title header-logo-container">
            <header-logo-dropdown></header-logo-dropdown>
        </div>

        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <a class="button  bar-header__iconprofile" href="#/user"><i class="icon iconSilver profile item-silver"></i> </a>
        </ion-nav-buttons>

    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-view>
        <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
        </ion-nav-view>
    </ion-view>

</ion-pane>
```

Comment: Please, post your directive code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed by removing "title" class from my directive wrapper div (.header-logo-container), the problem was that Ionic uses title class in navigation to render ion-view title string there, therefore it was removing the directive by re-rendering title class.

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as I can tell you used it right (If you directive is correct)
2. I think you used `ionNavView` and `ionView` in the wrong order

From the [Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)

```
<ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar> 
<ion-nav-view> 
    <ion-view view-title="My Page"> 
        <ion-content> Hello! </ion-content> 
    </ion-view> 
</ion-nav-view>
```

Maybe this solves your problem

Comment: You are right, it was in a wrong order, but correcting it did not help my problem.